# Is there any plan for the DC comic's superhero crossover movie?

Tags: comic-adaptation, crossovers

I like the crossover movies like *Alien Vs Predator*, *Avengers* etc. But I want to know if there is any plan for the DC comic character crossover film such as [*Justice League*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League). Where we can see Superman, Batman, Wonder Woman, Green Lantern, Flash, Hawkgirl and Martian Manhunter together.

Are there any plans for it in future or not?

Comment: Whereas I both like *Nolan*'s realistic and dark *Batman*, as well as the last overly nostalgic *Superman*, they won't work together in any reasonable way. So they will have to reboot either of those (and introduce rubbish like *Wonder Woman*). I just hope they don't just rereboot *Batman* and unrealistify/comicify him again to align him with the other heros (but well, it's the dollar that makes the movies and not common sense, so I'm sure there are plans for it).

Comment: @ChristianRau they can do justice league as a spin-off (without any connection to batman/superman movies) and wonder woman is important to justice league as she is a love interest of batman.

Comment: I completely agree with @ChristianRau. However, Batman is definitely in for a reboot in 2015 (possibly with Robin) - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877830/ . So your reboot theory is mostly coming true :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_in_other_media) Says-**

> When the Los Angeles Times interviewed Warner Bros. president Jeff Robinov, they speculated on the future of DC Comics' properties and believed a new Justice League film was in the works. They stated, following the 2011 launch of the Green Lantern film, Warner Bros. are "to release new Batman and Superman films in 2012 and Justice League, a teaming of DC's top heroes, in 2013."[34] However, there is no official word if the film is happening or not and how the Superman film being pushed back to the summer of 2013 would affect it. However, it was later announced that the film may be released in 2015.

And under the [Batman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%28film_series%29) heading:

> With the conclusion of Christopher Nolan's current trilogy, Warner Bros. is rumored to be producing a Justice League film, targeted for a 2015 release. With the Batman franchise being revamped to fit into the Justice League universe, Nolan and his wife, Emma Thomas, will stay on as producers for the project.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_in_other_media) Justice League article -

> At the 2013 San Diego Comic-Con Zack Snyder, director of Man of Steel,
>   confirmed an upcoming sequel for Man of Steel currently known as
>   Batman/Superman, though the official title is yet to be announced; the
>   movie is slated for release on July 17, 2015. The film will star Henry
>   Cavill reprising his role as Clark Kent/Superman and many of the first
>   film's cast are set to return. Ben Affleck will also join the cast as
>   Bruce Wayne/Batman. Flash and Justice League films are rumored to be
>   released in 2016 and 2017 respectively

Answer (score 4):

Digging a little on IMDB, I came across [The Justice League Part One](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0974015/).

I am guessing the spectacular response to Avengers should hurry them along...

> In January 2008, Warner Bros. announced the film was on indefinite
>   hold, allowing options to lapse for the cast. The studio felt the
>   script needed perfecting, which was impossible because of the
>   2007-2008 Writers Guild of America strike

Found [**another link**](http://scifimafia.com/2011/03/nolan-to-produce-batman-reboot-after-the-dark-knight-rises-warner-prepping-the-flash-and-wonder-woman-movies/) which points to the JLA movie being in the works.

> Just yesterday, we brought you the news that Warner Bros. president
>   Jeff Robinov reportedly stated that the brothers Warner are planning a
>   Justice League feature film for a 2013 release, after Zack Snyder‘s
>   forthcoming Superman: Man of Steel hits theaters in 2012.
>
> Today, the LA Times reports that Jeff Robinov has confirmed that the
>   Justice League script is in development, though he wouldn’t reveal who
>   was penning the screenplay. The new Warner Bros. president also stated
>   that the Batman film franchise will be rebooted after Christopher
>   Nolan‘s impending return to Gotham with The Dark Knight Rises.

Comment: I don't know how accurate that second link is, as it's a year old and since then, DC had *Green Lantern* bomb.  GL was the first step towards that Justice League film.